# C: prime factoring

Tags: c, prime-factoring

How do you test for primes with the IsPrime method below? I cannot seem to get the printf to work in my IsPrime method and no errors were thrown.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int IsPrime(unsigned int number) {
   if (number <= 1) {
      return 0; // zero and one are not prime
      printf("zero and one are not prime.");
      }
   unsigned int i;
   for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
      if (number % i == 0) {
         return 0;
         printf("not a prime.");
      }
   }
   return 1;
   printf("You've found a prime!");
   }

int main(void) {
   int a;

   printf("Please input an integer value: ");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   if(a >= 1 && a <= 1000) {
      printf("You entered: %d\n", a);
      IsPrime(a);
   }
   else {
      printf("Error! Please enter a value between 1 and 1000.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why downvotes? This is a programming question...

Comment: Enable & listen to compiler warnings and you wouldn't need to ask question like these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're `return`-ing from function before `printf`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `printf` statement after `return;` It's an easy fix, just swap the two instructions.